# How to set `border-radius` of `paper-listbox` inside `paper-dropdown-menu`?

Tags: css, polymer, polymer-2.x

I am trying to round the corners of a `paper-listbox`, which is contained in a `paper-dropdown-menu`. However, the following CSS doesn't change the border radius as I would've expected:

```
paper-listbox {
  border-radius: 14pt !important;
  --paper-listbox: {
    border-radius: 14pt;
    overflow: hidden;
  };
}
```

How can I set the `border-radius` of this `paper-listbox`?

*Screenshot:*

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The internal DOM of `<paper-dropdown-menu>` looks something like this:

```
  <paper-menu-button>
    <iron-dropdown>
      <div slot="dropdown-content" class="dropdown-content">
        <slot name="dropdown-content"></slot> <!-- user's slot content of paper-dropdown-menu is inserted here -->
      </div>
    </iron-dropdown>
  </paper-menu-button>
```

So this user code:

```
<paper-dropdown-menu>
  <paper-listbox slot="dropdown-content"> <!-- user's slot content -->
  </paper-listbox>
</paper-dropdown-menu>
```

becomes:

```
<paper-dropdown-menu>
  <paper-menu-button>
    <iron-dropdown>
      <div slot="dropdown-content" class="dropdown-content">
        <paper-listbox>  <!-- user's slot content inserted -->
        </paper-listbox>
      </div>
    </iron-dropdown>
  </paper-menu-button>
</paper-dropdown-menu>
```

In [`<paper-menu-button>`](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/paper-menu-button), the [`div.dropdown-content`](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-menu-button/blob/42d931d/paper-menu-button.html#L133-L135) container is [styled](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-menu-button/blob/42d931d/paper-menu-button.html#L86-L94) to show a box-shadow (via [`--shadow-elevation-2dp`](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-styles/blob/b16bd7a/shadow.html#L27-L31)), making the square edges of the `<div>` appear. The CSS you used to style the `<paper-listbox>` indeed styles the listbox, but the square edges you saw were actually from the listbox's parent (`div.dropdown-content`) with its box-shadow edges. You can override the styles of `div.dropdown-content` with the [`--paper-menu-button-content`](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/paper-menu-button/elements/paper-menu-button#styling) mixin, as shown in the following steps:

1. Apply a class to your `<paper-dropdown-menu>`:

   ```
   <paper-dropdown-menu class="dropdown">
   ```
2. Create a style for that class that sets [`--paper-menu-button-content`](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/paper-menu-button/elements/paper-menu-button#styling):

   ```
   <style>
     .dropdown {
       --paper-menu-button-content: {
         border-radius: 14pt;
       }
     }
   </style>
   ```

```js
window.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', () => {
  class XFoo extends Polymer.Element {
    static get is() { return 'x-foo'; }

    static get properties() {
      return {
        customers: {
          type: Array,
          value: () => [
            'Alice',
            'Bob',
            'Charlie',
            'David',
          ]
        }
      };
    }
  }
  customElements.define(XFoo.is, XFoo);
});
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/2.6.0.2/lib/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-listbox/paper-listbox.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-item/paper-item.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-dropdown-menu/paper-dropdown-menu.html">
  <link rel="import" href="neon-animation/web-animations.html">
</head>
<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
      <style>
        .dropdown {
          --paper-menu-button-content: {
            border-radius: 14pt;
          }
        }
      </style>

      <paper-dropdown-menu id="customer"
                           class="dropdown"
                           placeholder="Select Customer">
        <paper-listbox id="customerList"
          slot="dropdown-content"
          attr-for-selected="value"
          selected="[[customer]]">
          <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[customers]]" as="customer">
            <paper-item value="[[customer]]">[[customer]]</paper-item>
          </template>
        </paper-listbox>
      </paper-dropdown-menu>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

Comment: I have tried that, and am still getting square corners.  Maybe I am selecting the wrong element? I attached a screenshot.

Comment: Do you have a repro?

Comment: I'm not sure how to replicate in JSBin, etc., but am having trouble styling the element even in DevTools.

Comment: @Matthew You can fork this [codepen](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/PBJbqP?editors=1010), showing exactly what you've tried.

Comment: The usage of the `<paper-dropdown-menu>` was key to your question. See updated answer.

Comment: Oh, I see!  I still don't fully understand the composability of mixins.  At one point I tried the `--paper-listbox` selector inside `paper-dropdown-menu { }`... Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

`<paper-listbox>` found you a custom-property to style the element:

```
Custom property                     | Description                   | Default 
------------------------------------|-------------------------------|-----------------------
`--paper-listbox-background-color`  | Menu background color         | `--primary-background-color`
`--paper-listbox-color`             | Menu foreground color         | `--primary-text-color`
`--paper-listbox`                   | Mixin applied to the listbox  | `{}`
```

The `--paper-listbox` can be useful for your case :

```html
<dom-module id="x-app">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
          --paper-listbox: {
              border-radius: 14pt;
              border: solid 1px blue;
              /* you need to hide overflow */
              overflow: hidden;
          }
      }

      /* OR (if you have multiple listbox with different styles) */
      
      paper-listbox.radius {
          --paper-listbox: {
              border-radius: 14pt;
              border: solid 1px blue;
              overflow: hidden;
          }
      }
    </style>

    <paper-listbox class="radius">
      <paper-item>a</paper-item>
      <paper-item>b</paper-item>
      <paper-item>c</paper-item>
    </paper-listbox>
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: I am not able to get this to work... What does the purpose of hiding the overflow?

Comment: @Matthew hiding overflow is at your convenance, depends if you want to see `paper-items`'s squared corner out of your 'radiused' `paper-listbox`, also unless your project require to work on printer, 'pt' is not recommended for screens, i don't know if it affect your issue but this is not recommended for screens.